# Borra todos mis registros al igual que modifica

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

El detalle que al utilizar los botones modificar o eliminar aplica el cambio en todos los registros existentes, no solo en uno

```
       <form action="nuevo_prod2.php" method="POST" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 
     10px 5px;">
    <label>Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" id="Nombre" name="Nombre" required/><br> </form>
```

asi todos los registros que solicito, y esto es el back end

```
<?php   
NuevoProducto($_POST['Nombre'], $_POST['Edad'], $_POST['Correo'], $_POST['Fecha'],$_POST['Color']);

function NuevoProducto($nombre, $edad, $correo, $fecha, $color)
{
    include 'conexion.php';
    $sentencia= "INSERT INTO tablita (Nombre, Edad, Correo, Fecha, Color) VALUES ('".$nombre."', 
 '".$edad."', '".$correo."', '".$fecha."', '".$color."') ";
    $conexion->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al ingresar los datos".mysqli_error($conexion));
}
?>
```

saben ¿porque me hace modificaciones en todos los registros?

Comment: No relacionado con la pregunta en sí, pero importante: lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo prevenirla en PHP. El código compartido contiene vulnerabilidades graves de seguridad y no debería usarse en entornos de producción.

Comment: Si el problema es que se actualizan todos los registros después de enviar el formulario deberías compartir el código completo del formulario (parece que tienes las opciones de añadir y actualizar juntas), así como todo el código que se ejecuta al enviar el formulario (incluido el código de actualizar). ¿Puede que se estén llamando ambos métodos?